# Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") fails while Outlook has focus

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I am trying to automate Outlook using COM, and we are having terrible problems with Outlook crashing at arbitrary points when trying to use MAPI methods (eg Outlook.Recipient r = MAPI.CreateRecipient("me@there.com")).
One solution that has been suggested is to use Marshal.GetActiveObject() instead of new Outlook.Application().
This appears to work fine, however I have run into a very strange issue - the code fires up a copy of outlook and tries to get the application object, but calls to Marshal.GetActiveObject throw a System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exception while Outlook is the active application (Has the focus).
If I run the below code, the try keeps failing over and over.
However, if I hit ALT-TAB or click anywhere such that Outlook is no longer the active application, the code INSTANTLY succeeds. 
Any ideas why? Failing that, does anyone have code that will de-focus outlook, so the code succeeds?

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace MAPI_Repro
    {
        class FakeTest
        {
            public Outlook.Application oApp;
            public Outlook.NameSpace MAPI;

            public void DoTest(){
                if (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() == 0)
                {
                    var process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("outlook.exe"));
                }
                while (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }

                bool success = false;
                while (!success)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Waiting for Marshal.GetActiveObject");
                    try
                    {
                        // This FAILS while Outlook is the active application.
                        // As soon as you hit ALT-TAB or click another app, this succeeds.
                        oApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Outlook.Application;
                        success = true;
                        Debug.WriteLine("SUCCESS");
                    }
                    catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException exp)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("FAILED " + exp);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }


                MAPI = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
                MAPI.Logon("", "", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This belongs over at Stackoverflow.  Migration started for you.  No need to do anything until it is indeed moved.  You can avoid the failure by doing a check to make sure Outlook isn't the active application.